# LazyInitializationException after upgrade to IIS 7.5

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord

We develop a ASP.NET 4.0 / MVC 3 web application, using Active Record as database abstraction.

To be able to use lazy relations inside views, we are using the SessionScopeWebModule from ActiveRecord documentation [here](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/usersguide/web.html).

The app **works fine on our current** Win 2003 / IIS 6 machine, but only on our new Win 2008 R2 / IIS 7.5 it throws a LazyInitializationException when a controller or view tries to access a lazy relation. After changing to manual session handling (also explained in the doc link above), it works again.

I wonder what the difference is, as the manual states that both approaches do basically the same thing.

Comment: did you register the web module under system.webServer/modules? are you using integrated or classic pipeline?

Comment: hi, please provide this as an answer - configuring IIS to show details on the 500 error told me about the same thing. is there a way to write a iis7 integrated and iis6 compatible Web.config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running an ASP.NET app in IIS 7+ in integrated pipeline, you need to register the http modules under the system.webServer / modules section of web.config.

It's possible to have a single web.config for both IIS 6 and IIS 7+, [see this article](http://arcware.net/use-a-single-web-config-for-iis6-and-iis7/).

Otherwise, run in classic pipeline mode, it will behave just as in IIS 6.